# Python3 Type str doesn't support the buffer API on string comparaison

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I just moved from python 2.7 to python 3.4 and I get a type error on a simple comparaison of string, I don't understand the error message, my code worked fine in python 2. What am I doing wrong ?

> Error message: TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
>
> The error is on line 6

```
def wait_prompt(device, msg, timing, error_msg, port):

    output = device.readline()
    t_end = time.time() + timing
    counter = 0
    while not msg in output:
        if time.time() < t_end:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            device.write("\r")
            output = device.readline()
            device.flush()
            loading_msg("msg",counter)
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            error(error_msg, port)
            return 0
    return 1

def initialize_router(device):

    if wait_prompt(device, "[yes/no]:", 10, "waiting for question [yes/no]", port[0]) == 0:
        return 0
```

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24928908/2382792

Comment: What is line 6? You should add the complete traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have all the context, but I assume `output` is of type `bytes` and `msg` is a `str`? If you change `msg in output` (line 6) to `msg.encode('utf-8') in output` (or whatever other encoding you use), then it should work.

This error will occur whenever you search for a `str` in `bytes`, encoding the string with a particular character encoding will turn it into a byte sequence and make the two more readily comparable.

Comment: i modified the output = device.readline() to output = str(device.read()) to forc it in a string and it works thanks for this ;)

Comment: That's actually better indeed. _Decode early, encode late_